# Saving files on sd card on android 11

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage, scoped-storage

I would like to save photos on the external app directory on the sd card on Android 11.
What is the proper way to do this?
Am I constrained to use SAF API with system picker triggered by action ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE where user have to select a folder on sd card?

Or maybe I can use this method:

```
File[] externalStorageVolumes =ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(mContext, null);
```

and assume that if the sd card is available it will be on `externalStorageVolumes[1]`?
This worked on my 2 devices (Samsung j1 with android 5, and Samsung s10 with Android 10), but I don't have the opportunity to access more devices to test it.

Comment: `it will be on externalStorageVolumes[1]?` Yes. And you can continue to use that app specific directory.

Comment: Further on two Android 11 API 30 emulators Android OS already created a DCIM directory. You can create your subfolders in them and or write .jpg files in them.

Comment: You can test on API 30 emulators too.

Answer (score 4):

On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on [external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-access-files).

Try Media storage [api](https://androidexplained.github.io/android/android11/scoped-storage/2020/09/29/file-saving-android-11.html)

Or target old android 10 and set requestLegacyExternalStorage=true in [manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#write-files-secondary-storage-volumes)

Comment: `apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage.` App specific directories are always created by Android OS and can be found in getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: @blackapps and is it required `Storage Permission`?

Comment: Not for the directories delivered by those three functions.